# Uploading files using Web API OData v3

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

I have done a lot of research in the internet to find how to upload file with **Web API OData** with no luck..
Would appreciate if you could share an example that demonstrates how to upload file via **Wep API Odata**.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Media Entities or Named Stream Properties could address your requirement. For more detail, please reference the sections 10.3.6 and 10.3.7 in http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/